# Two unknowns in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I have a problem in my maths book which says

> Find the arithmetic sequence in which $T_8 = 11$ and $T_{10}$ is the additive inverse of $T_{17}$

I don't have a first term of common difference to solve it, so I managed to make two equations to find the first term and common difference from them. Here they are.

first equation $a + 7d = 11$

second equation since $T_{10} + T_{17} = 0$

therefore $a+9d + a+16d = 0 ~~\Rightarrow~~ 2a + 25d = 0$

So what I did is subtracting the first equation from the second one to form this equation with two unknowns $a – 18d = 11$

This is what I came up with and I can't solve the equations, any help?

Comment: Dont you know how to solve these equations??

Comment: You get $d=-2$, $a = 25$.

Comment: "Dont you know how to solve these equations??"  Apparently not.

Comment: Why is that an problem?  What did you come up with?  You said "and I can't proceed no more," which means you *don't* know how to solve them.  If you could solve them then you *would* be able to proceed.

Comment: @KingTut Can you write the steps please?

Comment: @fleablood My bad, sorry.

Comment: Try to get $a_n=-2n+27$

Comment: If you subtract you get $a + 18d = 1$.  Not $a - 18d = 11$.

Comment: @fleablood So this means I should subtract the second equation from the first one, right?

Comment: Try subtracting *twice* the first equation from the second to eliminate $a$.  That will enable you to solve for $d$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Genius solution, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Three things i)  [2a + 25d=0]-[a+7d = 11] => [a +18d = -11] (my bad, sorry)  ii) if you have [2a + 25d=0] => 2a =-25d => a = -12$\frac 12$d (you can plug those in and iii)  [2a + 25d=0] - 2x[a+7d=11] => 11d = -22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve linear equations with n variables, you need a minimum of n equations. Here, we have 2 variables and 2 equations, so it can be solved.

There are many methods to solve the equations. But the most common method is elimination method.

In this method, you multiply an equation with a constant, such that the coefficient of the equation becomes equal to the coefficient of the other equation. Then you subtract them, and you are left with one variable.

You have the equations:

$$ a + 7d = 11 $$
$$ 2a + 25d = 0 $$

Now multiply the first equation by 2, you get:

$$2a+14d=22$$

Subtract this with the second equation. You get:

$$ 2a+14d - 2a - 25d = 22$$
$$ - 11d = 22 $$

This gives $d= -2 $. Putting this value in first equation, we get:
$$a = 11 - 7.(-2) = 25 $$

So we have, $a=25, d=-2$

Answer (score 0):

A: $T_8 = 11$ means $a + 7d = 11$

B: $T_{10}=$ additive inverse of $T_{17}$ means $(a+ 9d) + (a+ 16d) = 0$ or $2a + 25d = 0$.

Substract A) from B) and you get:

C:  $a + 18d = -11$  (you subtracted wrong).

Well, subtract A: from C: now.

D:$11d = -22$

So $d = -2$

Plug it into A:

and you get $a + 7(-2) = 11$

$a - 14 = 11$

$a = 25$

===

Note.  Well you has $2a + 25d = 0$, that's enough to make a relation betweend $a$ and $d$.

$2a = -25d$

$a = -\frac {25}2 d$

Plug that into $A$ and $-\frac {25}2d + 7d = 11$

$\frac {-25 +14}2d = 11$

$\frac {-11}2d = 11$

$-11d = 22$

$d = -2$

Plug that into $A$.

Or

when you subtracted A: for B:  Instead of subtracting A; subtract $2$ times A:

$2a + 25d = 0$ and subtract $2a + 14d = 22$ to get $11d = -22$.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple .
a+7d=11
And second eq is 2a+ 25d.
Multiply the first eq by cofficient of a from second eq . i.e.,
2a+14d=22 and
 2a+25d=0 
By subtracting both equations we get 
d=-2.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you Carlos for giving me suggestion